# Do i really need to define models in sequelizejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

I'm playing around with expressjs for a while and now the time has come to connect to a mysql database. Now i'm searching for a way to write and retrieve data from it. Normally i'm creating the database tables with MySQL Workbench. I'm using MySQL because of the ability of using ForeignKeys. Couldn't figure out yet how to do it in other database types...

Currently i'm more used to [medoo](http://medoo.in/) for PHP. It only connected to a database and gave me the ability to access it in an object oriented way.

Is there a similar module for nodejs out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [knex](http://knexjs.org/) for a sql-builder library, it's pretty solid and looks sort of similar to medoo (but it uses Promises and is asynchronous).

Comment: Thanks, this one looks good. I've played around a little and was able to get all data i need. Seems pretty easy. Faster than writing all the queries by myself.